# Como mostrar un sitio en distintaos tamaños?

Tags: web, iframe

Quería saber como se puede hacer para mostrar dentro de una web como se ve un sitio en celular, tablet y pc de escritorio

Me imagino que se puede con iframe pero no se como poner las distintas resoluciones para que lo cargue como se vería en cada dispositivo.

Es para hacer un muestreo de sitios, de como se ve en los distintos formatos, siendo el sitio resposive obviamente

Yo lo que quería es mostrar en como dividir la página en tres partes iguales y en cada una mostrar como se ve en cada dispositivo.

Todo el resto lo hago con bootstrap eso no hay drama.

Espero me puedan ayudar
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

no se si te refieras a esto, pero en chrome si le das a inspeccionar puedes pre visualizar el contenido web en diferentes resoluciones:
[image: Inspección de contenido]

Comment: No, lo que quiero lo siguiente. Tengo una web propia donde quiero poner páginas de amigos pero en ves de poner el link quiero poner para que muestre la misma como si fuera una foto pero del tío en ese momento. La ideas que sea vea esas web en una sección donde cada una se pueda visualizar como se ve en cada dispositivo.